# Getting different sizes for arrays

Tags: c

When I pass a char array through a method and use the sizeof method, it comes out different than if I were to use sizeof directly. Anybody know why and how I can fix this simple mistake?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char c[5];
    char car[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };;
    int num = my_strlen(c);

    printf("%d \n", sizeof(c));
    printf("%d \n", sizeof(car));

    printf("%d \n", my_strlen(c));
    printf("%d \n", my_strlen(car));


    return 0;
}

int my_strlen(char s[]) // returns number of characters in a string
{
    return sizeof(s);
}
```

Output:

```
5
3
8
8
```

Comment: `printf("%d \n", sizeof(c));` and `printf("%d \n", sizeof(car));` invoke *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. Format `%zu` should be used to print `size_t`, which is `sizeof`'s result.

Comment: You should declare or define functions *before* using them.

Comment: You can't pass an array into a function, and you aren't passing an array into a function here.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays decay to pointers when used as arguments, this implies that

```
int my_strlen(char s[])
{
  return sizeof(s);
}
```

is instead

```
int my_strlen(char* s)
{
  return sizeof(s);
}
```

So `sizeof(s) == sizeof(char*) == sizeof(void*)` which apparently is 8 bytes on your machine because you are running on a 64 architecture.